# Return data only into an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am performing a Mongodb collection.find using node.js, how do I return only the data without the column name into an array.

```
var cursor = collection.find( { title: title }, { title: 1, _id: 0 });
cursor.sort( { title: 1 });
cursor.toArray(function (err, all_documents) { .... });
```

> ```
> {"title":"MongoDB Overview"}
> {"title":"NoSQL Overview"}
> {"title":"Tutorials Point Overview"}
> ```

Comment: You can map it after the fact - `var arr = all_documents.map(function(d) { return d.title });`

Comment: Can you give us some sample output you expect to see?

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.find(...).toArray().map( function(u) { return u.title; } )
```

or

```
var result = []
collection.find().forEach(function(u) { result.push(u.title) })
```

Comment: `forEach` and `map` are client side use  `aggregate()` and the `$push` operator.